# Como tratar o usuário logado em um sistema MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou criando um *framework MVC* a algumas semanas (desenvolvendo-o e utilizando-o ao mesmo tempo), cheguei na parte de criar o sistema de autenticação.

Então gostaria de criar um meio de que eu configurasse quais rotas o usuário pode acessar quando não está autenticado nas aplicações que for criada em cima do *Framework*, sem ter que ficar verificando a cada método se o usuário está autenticado ou não.

Já tenho o trecho de código onde chamo o *controller* para ter uma ideia do que estou desenvolvendo.

```
class Application {

   public static function RUN() {

      $request = New Request();

      $class = '\\Controller\\'.$request->class.'Controller';

      if (!empty($request->post['mvc:model'])){
         $model = '\Model\\' . array_remove($request->post, 'mvc:model') . 'Model';
         $param = New $model($request->post);
      } else if (!empty($request->lost))
         $param = $request->lost;
      else {
         $param = NULL;
      }

      try {
         $app = New $class();
         $action = $request->action;

         if (!is_null($param) && !empty($param))
            $app->$action($param);
         else 
            $app->$action();

      } catch (SystemException $e) {
         if ( strpos(Exceptions::E_FILENOTFOUND.'|'.Exceptions::E_CLASSNOTEXIST, $e->getCode()) !== FALSE){
            $app = New \Controller\FileNotFound();
            $app->file = $class;
            $app->index();
         } else {
            $app = New \Controller\ErrorController();
            $app->message = $e->getMessage();
            $app->error = $class;
            $app->index();
         }

      }


      $app->output();
   }
}
```

A questão é que não estou muito afim de ficar chamando um método para verificar se o usuário está autenticado a cada método que eu for criando. Então precisaria de uma forma para configurar no `Application::Run()` verificar se o usuário tem permissão pra acessar a rota solicitada.

Já existe algum padrão nos modelos MVC?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54282/discussion-on-question-by-kaduamaral-como-tratar-o-usuario-logado-em-um-sistema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro implementar como um plugin ou "hook".

Eu desenvolvo frameworks PHP há muitos anos. Na penúltima versão, construída em 2009, eu implementei leitura de permissões de usuários/login dentro do *Core* do framework porque caí nesse seu mesmo dilema. Como eu estava com pressa em ver resultado, construí o recurso de login e autenticação dentro do *Core*.

Mais tarde, com anos de uso e diversos casos, percebi que seria melhor separado, como se fosse um plugin, até porque implementar tal recurso no *Core* em si, já estava ferindo o conceito *MVC*. A lógica é que login/autenticação pertence ao *Model*.

Num exemplo mais claro, por diversas vezes tive que construir algum site pequeno onde não precisava de login ou cadastro de usuários. Então aquele recurso nativo de permissões de usuários se tornava completamente inútil.

Vamos ver um exemplo prático de como implementar uma lógica com plugins/hooks?

```
class Core
{
    public function MainProcesses()
    {
        /**
        Aqui excecuta as rotinas comuns e nativas do framework, normalmente
        */

        /**
        Em algum ponto, vc deve decidir onde carregar os plugins/hooks
        */
        $this->MainProcessesHooks();
    }
    private function MainProcessesHooks()
    {
        /**
        Uma rotina que vai procurar por hooks registrados e configurados adequadamente para ser executado no método MainProcesses()

        Exemplo, aqui vc pode ter um plugin para verificar se um usuário está autenticado e setar suas permissões.

        A ideia aqui é fazer leitura de algum arquivo php, json, txt, enfim. Algo que seja rápido de carregar e processar. 
        Nesse arquivo, conterá informações sobre quais os hooks/plugins devem ser carregados aqui.
        */
         $p = '/path/absolute/of/app/Plugins/Core/MainProcesses.php';
         if (file_exists($p))
             include $p;
    }
}
```

Dentro de "MainProcesses.php"

```
<?php
include '/path/absolute/of/app/Model/Users/Plugins/Permissions.php';
include '/path/absolute/of/app/Model/OutroModelQualquer/Plugins/qualquer-outra-coisa.php';
```

Dessa forma, sempre que precisar adicionar funcionalidades no *Core* e funções nativas do framework, específicas de modelos negócios, poderá fazer sem apelas para gambiarras e destruindo o conceito MVC do aplicativo.

A ideia de um framework é não precisar mecher em suas rotinas nativas mesmo quando necessitar implementar um recurso muito específico de um modelo de negócios.

A grosso modo, essa lógica com carregamento de hooks/plugins, é uma gambiarra elegante. O que vai tornar o processo mais elegante ainda é qual conceito OOP você vai conseguir implementar sob esse esquema. Nesse ponto vamos começar a falar de paradigmas de programação e coisas muito complexas. Procure não pensar muito em coisas que complicam. Mantenha o padrão *KISS* (Keep It Simple, Stupid).

*Os exemplos acima são meramente didáticos. Nomenclaturas, estruturas de sistema de arquivos, semântica, padrão de código, visibilidade de métodos e a lógica em si são meramente ilustrativos.

**Segurança**

Nesse esquema de execução de plugins/hooks, deve-se estar atento a segurança. Deve ser bastante restritivo e organizado sobre o quê um plugin pode executar.

Portanto, jamais permita que um usuário comum (não autorizado) consiga incluir um plugin, pois, obviamente abre brechas para pessoas má intencionadas ou ações adicentais.

Comment: Muito boa a sugestão, com certeza irei testar e tentar aplica-la. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um arquivo junto as pastas de aplicação que se chama `appsconfig.php`, nesse arquivo adicionei os seguintes dados:

```
'authentication' => [
   'controller' => 'Auth',
   'action' => 'logged',
   'redirect' => [
      'controller' => 'Login',
      'action' => 'index'
   ],
   'routes' => [ // Routes allowed
      'login' => ['index', 'authenticate']
   ]
]
```

Ali coloquei o *controller* e *action* responsável pela verificação da autenticação `Auth::logged()` que retorna um booleano (esse método é implementado pela aplicação e não pelo framework. Ali também coloquei os dados para o redirecionamento `redirect` e as rotas permitidas quando não estiver autenticado.

Criei o método `checkPermission` no Controller principal:

```
private function checkPermission() {

    if ($this->config->app->authentication) {

        $authentication = $this->config->app->authentication;

        $auth = "\\Controller\\{$authentication->controller}Controller";
        $check = $authentication->action;

        if (!($auth::$check())){
            if (!property_exists($authentication->routes, $this->request->controller)){
                $this->request->redirect(Route::href("{$authentication->redirect->controller}/{$authentication->redirect->action}"));
            }
            else if (
                property_exists($authentication->routes, $this->request->controller) && 
                !in_array($this->request->action, (array)$authentication->routes->{$this->request->controller})
            ){
                $this->request->redirect(Route::href("{$authentication->redirect->controller}/{$authentication->redirect->action}"));
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

<sub>Sei que há uma forma melhor de se fazer isso, porém por enquanto assim está resolvendo. Deixarei a pergunta em aberto, aguardando outras possíveis soluções.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso existe uma tabela no banco (permissions) onde ficam as permissões de acesso dos perfis (Admin, Editor, Comum), nessa tabela é colocado os endereços que o usuário pode transitar.. quando o usuário é logado as permissões são colocadas na $_SESSION e sempre que for acessar qualquer endereço essa rotina define se o usuário tem permissão ou não.
Já na segunda parte caso não exista nenhuma permissão na session ele verifica as permissões de visitante (**$routes = Routes::guest()**)

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['permissions']) && sizeof($_SESSION['permissions']) > 0){
        foreach ($_SESSION['permissions'] as $i => $value) {
            if(@preg_match($value['route'], $url) || $value['route'] == $url){
                return $value['allow'];
            }
        }
    }
    $routes = Routes::guest();
    foreach ($routes as $route => $array) {
        if(@preg_match($route, $url) || $route == $url){
            return $routes[$route];
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Só quis te dar uma ideia de como pode ser feita, você precisa fazer alguns ajustes e tornar o mais modular possível, nessa estratégia tenho três arquivos  trabalhando (index.php?url, Router::mapping(), Permissions::check());

Comment: No caso esse código que você postou é o `Permissions::check()`?

Comment: Isso mesmo... no caso preg_match é usado porque a rota pode ser descrita com expressão regular também, mas $value['route'] == $url resolve para uma rota do tipo '/posts/add'